# Firebase Auth (android) email verification need some advice

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

After creating user with email and password I am calling  `#sendEmailVerification()`. What I know is that Firebase create user  with email and password first and then send verification mail to that user.

Tthis works fine if the user is accessible to that mail id and verify the mail which makes `user.isEmailVerified = true`.

But, if user fails to verify mail or he/she can not access the provided mail, the email Id will get locked because the account is created with that email id.

My question is that what to do when user fails to verify email?

Comment: Maybe remind the user that they need to verify before using the application with a simple Toast message

Comment: yes give an istruction that create user with an accessible mail id

Comment: Yes i already show toast message . But if user dont want to verify then in that case their email id get locked in firebase.  What i need is that if user dont verify then delete their account.

Answer (score 1):

If you record the fact that a user registered in the Firebase Database, you can use the Admin SDK to regularly clean out users with unverified email addresses.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    if (!userRecord.emailVerified) {
      admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
        .then(function() {
          console.log("Successfully deleted user");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
        });
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response frank.  Do i need to write this piece of code on server side?

Comment: Yes. The Admin SDK should only be used on hardware you trust, since it runs with full admin access to the Firebase services.

Comment: One more questions  does firebase provide automated feature  for something  like giving time limit for email verification . and if user fails to verify within time. therir account  will be deleted .

Comment: No. That's the reason I wrote an answer on how you can build it yourself.